# Use of color: inside li element

Tags: css

In the following example the color selectors in the `<li>` styles are not having an effect but the `background-color` and `font-weight` ones work just right.

If it isn't just operator-error but some subtle feature conflict I'd love to know where to find the reference for the next odd thing I trip over. I've tried removing the background-color and using the numeric value for the color.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

<head>
  <!-- based on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Pseudo-classes_and_pseudo-elements -->

  <title>Untitled</title>
  <meta name="generator" content="BBEdit 8.2">
  <style>
    ul {
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    li {
      padding: 3px;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
    
    li:nth-of-type(even) {
      background-color: #ccc;
      color: darkred;
    }
    
    li:nth-of-type(odd) {
      background-color: #eee;
    }
    
    li:hover {
      font-weight: bold;
      color: red;
    }
    
    a {
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    a:hover {
      text-decoration: underline;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">United Kingdom</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Germany</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Finland</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Russia</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Spain</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Poland</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I assume you're asking why your links aren't changing color?

Comment: "li:hover" should be "li a:hover" if you want the links to turn red on hover

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the color on the anchor when it is hovered.

```
a:hover {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Currently it's using the default color for anchors when hovered and `red` is not being inherited.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

<head>
  <!-- based on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Pseudo-classes_and_pseudo-elements -->

  <title>Untitled</title>
  <meta name="generator" content="BBEdit 8.2">
  <style>
    ul {
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    li {
      padding: 3px;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
    
    li:nth-of-type(even) {
      background-color: #ccc;
      color: darkred;
    }
    
    li:nth-of-type(odd) {
      background-color: #eee;
    }
    
    li:hover {
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    a {
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    a:hover {
      color: red;
      text-decoration: underline;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">United Kingdom</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Germany</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Finland</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Russia</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Spain</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Poland</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

---

FWIW, I'd switch from the HTML4 doctype to an HTML5 doctype.

`<!DOCTYPE html>`

Answer (score 0):

It's because there are more specific rules that are overriding your styles on the `li` elements.  Each browser has it's own set of default styles called "user agent styles", which are determined by the browser.  There is a user agent style for anchor tag `color`, but there isn't one for `font-weight`.  Because of this, the inherited value of `font-weight` is applied to your links on hover, but `color` is not.  Any value that is inherited has a lower "specificity" than any other style (even the default user agent styles) that might be applied.  As you can see from the image below, in chrome the color is set to `-webkit-link`.  There is a similar style in all other major browsers.

[image]

To correct the issue, you need to apply your style directly to the anchor.  You can do this with a rule for `li:nth-of-type(even) a`, `a:hover` (or `li:hover a` but I prefer to keep my `:hover` styles on an anchor only), et.al.  The point is, you need the style to be on the anchor itself.  Otherwise, it's just implicitly inherited and the browser will consider its own user agent styles to be the more specific ones.

Comment: Thanks.  This may help explain why I've always found css inscrutable. (I can find some of Firefox's rules in an obscure place under Developer Tools, but nothing that describes the styling of links. Oh well, lots to learn...).

Answer (score -1):

- Maybe try using hex colors instead of the way you have them typed?
- you could try putting the styles inline on the list? ie.
- try using applying the css to the a tags instead of to the li tag ie:

  a:hover{
     color:red;
  };
- try using the nth child selector instead of nth of type:

  ul > *:nth-child(2n)   <- for even
  ul > *:nth-child(2n-1)  <-for odd

I'm honestly not sure but I think something in the above should work. If not, please let me know and I'll try to help more.